# ios split array into sections based on compare result

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

I have an `array` of objects which I am currently sorting by `date` (the objects each have a `date` field on them).

I want to be able to split up this array into multiple sections, where each section contains the objects that have the same date. Is there already a supported mechanism for this?

Comment: Yes just implement UITableViewDataSource's numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: I need to be able to first figure out how many sections I need and how many rows in each one...That is the entire point of building this data struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no mechanism for this, other than the way I suggested in my comment:

I create a `nsmutabledict`, then I iterate over my sorted list of objects. For each object, I check the date, and see if there exists a key in my `dict` pertaining to that date. If so, I retrieve that value from the `dict` and append this `object` to that array. If not, I create a new `list` and insert it into the `dict` with the key pertaining to the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

will be useful. Write a predicate to get the filtered array of all the elements matching the date of the first item in the array. Add that array to a new mutable array, which is the object holding all the filtered arrays with matching dates.

Record that date as having been used. Iterate over the original array until you find a different date and repeat the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` operation. Keep doing this until you have covered all unique dates in the array.

I was going to suggest using NSSet to remove all the items that have been filtered already to reduce processing time but the number of items may be important, and depending on the objects NSSet could discard duplicates.

An optimisation could be to use NSSet to non-destructively create a set of unique dates from the original array and then iterate over that set, performing the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` operation. But whether that is practical depends on your data.

Comment: This seems like a pretty inefficient solution. I will be traversing the entire array once for each unique date that is present. I can simply do it in one traversal manually (create `nsmutabledict` to track dates, traverse sorted array, get date, see if date key exists in `dict`. If it does, append to the end of that key's value, else create a new `dict` key with a `nsmutablearray` as its value.

Comment: Sure, but without knowing about your data - plain NSDate or object containing NSDate? it is hard to suggest further.

Comment: It is an object containing an NSDate

Comment: Yes, I can get it done. I was just wondering if there was already a mechanism in place -- similar to how I don't have to implement my own sorting algo. If not, I can just use the method I mentioned.

Comment: @AtulBhatia, no, there is no canned way to do that. The way you are doing it is as good a way as any.

Comment: yeah I went ahead and implemented it that way. thanks!